# Android Java: Automatically send a notification based on a date condition already specified in the application

Tags: java, android, date, notifications, alarm

I'm building a plant care android application. The application stores the irrigation date on the database.
I'm retrieving that date from the database and I need the application to automatically send an irrigation reminder notification after a period of the last irrigation date. How can I do that in the Android application written with Java?

I tried out this ode but it required the user to specify the date manually. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-an-android-notification-to-a-specific-date-in-the-future

Answer (score 0):

I think JobScheduler can feet your needs.

Example for 1 notification per hour

```
val jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

        jobScheduler.schedule(
            JobInfo
                .Builder(1, ComponentName(this, JobServiceImpl::class.java))
                .setMinimumLatency(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1))
                .setBackoffCriteria(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .build()
        )
```

JobServiceImpl class

```
class JobServiceImpl : JobService() {
    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        return true
    }

override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    manager.notify(....your notification)

    return true
}
```

}

dont forget to add this

```
<service
            android:name=".JobServiceImpl"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

to your manifest.
Details about job scheduler can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)